# Consider $B\subset\Re^{n}$ a ball (open or closed). Show that for all $x\in B$, the set $B-\{x\}$ is connected.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I need a little help with "Consider $B\subset\Re^{n}$ a ball (open or closed). Show that for all $x\in B$, the set $B-\{x\}$ is connected".
First of all, i know that every ball (open or closed) is connected in $\Re^{n}$. I was thinking  in proof by contrapositive.

Comment: That's false for $n = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT is very easy to join any two points in the punctured ball with a path.  Therefore this set has one path (and therefore connected) component.